# Library to segment and classify binary or grayscale images

Tags: java, image-processing

I am interpreting scientific (STEM) images into their component parts and adding semantics. These images are born digital, noise-free and either binary (monochrome) or have a small number of colours. I would like Java libraries/methods to partition the images into the whitespace-separated components and to identify (classify) the resulting segments. A typical image is:

[image]

where I would want the extracted segments to include numerals and other characters (some rotated) and the asterisks in the diagram. [I will use other methods to extract the geometrical components - e.g. the bars) . I would also like the library to identify identical segments (e.g. 6 zero characters, 5 decimal points). I have successfully used Tesseract for characters but many of the segments may not belong to a Unicode character set (e.g. purpose-created symbols).

UPDATE: I have opened a bounty. I am only interested in libraries, NOT suggestions for algorithms as I have already written a prototype one. If the functionality is part of a larger system (e.g. I think JBIG2 has this functionality) please make it clear where the entry points are.

NOTE: "born-digital" means that the image was created without noise, clean lines unlike - say - scanned documents.

Comment: Sounds like a fun thing to do, but.. If, as you say, the images are born digital, wouldn't it be easier and more accurate to tap into the images' sources, rather than the images themselves? Or is that impossible for some reason?

Comment: They aren't under my control - I just read them from scientific papers. It's when the rch structure of a drawing package has been copied to (say) a PNG and I have to try to reconstruct the original. Segmentation is a key step. It seems the sort of thing that JBIG2 does

Answer (score 2):

I am only aware of [openCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html). With this you can analyze your image like:

- binarizing it (if you have a few colors or greyscale)
- gather blobs in Mat-objects
- get the position of those Mats to get the correct label (which should be a Mat for each letter)
- and then apply your algorithm to those Mats

Comment: oops, seems I've misread your question, but wait...

Comment: ... if you have trouble getting rotated chars, try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C You can easily port it to java (by hand if necessary)

Comment: Basically that is a different OCR-Engine, but you could enhance it with every character you need, regardless of scale and orientation. And it uses openCV as well.

Comment: If you have words, that could be misread by this engine like 'Ill' (capitalized 'ill') (but you have digital born images) you can use this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance like here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java

Comment: I am prepared for the Ill problem - it can only be solved by heuristics and some NLP.

Comment: I cannot preprime this with characters as I don't know the fonts

Comment: OpenCV is huge. If it has useful methods can you please identify them? Else I have to doo all the exploration mysels :-)

Comment: objects: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/core.html
methods: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/imgproc.html
I/O: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/highgui.html

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours together with http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp is useful